# Приложение может делать слишком много работы по его основному потоку

Tags: android

> The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

это сообщение получаю в logcat ,но Приложение после загрузки работает нормально и никаких ошибок  нет.

Хотел узнать что это значит, а будет ли влиять на память мобильник,можно как нибудь избавиться от этого ???

Comment: Нельзя выполнять больше задачи и задачи типа интернет, нельзя делать в основном потоке. Сделайте AsyncTask

Comment: у меня задачи загрузка звуков поэтому долго и никак не связена с интернетом. я использую класс soundPool и все делаю внтри фрагментов.   вот пример и таких у меня около 100   ,      mBearSound = Sound.loadSound(getContext(), "bear.mp3");

Comment: тогда получается это ошибка просто Warning, а не Error. Если так тогда можно не беспокоится, так как это gc срабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тогда получается это ошибка просто `Warning`, а не `Error`.

Если так тогда можно не беспокоится, так как это `gc` срабатывает